# $\phi : {F^{N_0}}\rightarrow{F^{N_0}}$ ,infinite vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$$\phi : {F^{N_0}}\rightarrow{F^{N_0}}$$

$$ x \mapsto {({x_{k+1}})}_{k \in {N_0}}$$ \

$\phi $ is called the left shift of F-vectorspace ${F^{N_0}}$

$\textbf{can  you please   give me an exemple how does  this function look like }$

is it correct when i write  like that  ;

$(x_0,x_1,x_2,......) \mapsto(x_1,x_2,x_3....,)$

my question is , is the last elment in $(x_1,x_2,x_3....,)$ 0 or x_0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it correct when i write  like that  ;
>
> $(x_0,x_1,x_2,......) \mapsto(x_1,x_2,x_3....,)$

Yes, that's exactly what happens.

---

> my question is , is the last elment in $(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots)$ 0 or x_0 ?

There is no such thing as "the last element of $(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots)$", so this question has no answer. If that sounds confusing, consider the question:

> What is the last element of $1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0\dots$?

which also does not have an answer.

Comment: but  from the start  set  we did remove an  element  , which  the  first , and the the  function  $\phi$ is $\in$$  End({F^{N_0}})$ which  means the length of x must be the same as  $\phi(x)$ am i not right  ?

Comment: @Mohbenay Yes, both lengths are the same - they are infinite.

Comment: @Mohbenay $x$ has one element for each index $i\in\mathbb N$. $\phi(x)$ **also** has one element for each index $i\in\mathbb N$. There's no difference in the "length" of the two vectors (note that the entire concept of "length" becomes hard to define for infinite vectors, but if you define it as the size of the index set, then the sizes of $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb N\setminus\{1\}$ are the same.

Comment: my  problem is , that  i have  a sub set from  ${F^{N_0}}$which is 
${F^{N_0}_{<n}}= \{x\in {F^{N_0}} \mid x_k=0, k>=n\}$ and  i must  prove that  ${F^{N_0}_{<n}}$ is  $\phi$ invarient

Comment: @Mohbenay That's a whole new question. I answered this question, now if you have additional questions, please follow the rules of this site and post the new question (if you think the question you asked **here** has been answered, then you should also accept the answer)

Comment: Yes , thank you   i will  :D

Comment: @Mohbenay And feel free to link the question in the comments here, so I can have a look at it.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2354670/eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors-of-phi-fn-0-rightarrowfn-0